# Ajax function not work properly

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc

I am new for ajax. I wrote ajax function, backend function using spring MVC. When I run code ajax function call backend function and return data correctly but ajax function call

```
error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: "+ e);
        },
```

it not call
    success : function(data) {
    }

This is my ajax function

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "getAllDansalJSON.html",
        data:"", 
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 10000,
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
            alert(data.message);
            if (data.message=="SUCCESS") {
                alert(data);
                setMarkers(map);
            }
             else {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: "+ e);
        },
        done : function(x) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
```

This is my back end function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllDansalJSON", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody DansalaJSONRespons  getAccountBalance() {
    DansalaJSONRespons dansalaJSONRespons=new DansalaJSONRespons();
    try{

        List<DansalaBean> list= dansalaDAO.getDansalList();
        dansalaJSONRespons.setDansalAllList(list);
        dansalaJSONRespons.setMessage("SUCCESS");
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        dansalaJSONRespons.setMessage("INVALID");
    }
    return dansalaJSONRespons;


}
```

Comment: are you sure it is `.html` the URL you are calling `url: getAllDansalJSON.html` ?

Comment: Any issue in console?

Comment: Is the controller not called, or only the callback "success" handler. please share the excpetion / log output from the controller with us. You also need to add the 'produces = "application/json"' to your controller request Mapping

Comment: you should try url : "getAllDansalJSON" and the browser debug console will print some error message. check and provide it for debugging.

Comment: In your ajax code the url is `getAllDansalJSON.html` however in your controller method,the url is called `/getAllDansalJSON`,they need to keep the same.

Comment: Yes. I used url: getAllDansalJSON.html its work. it called back-end method. @Dario

Comment: Yes. I have an error message in console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)" @kalai

Comment: i think your url is incorrect,its not possible to write server side code on html page.

Comment: Yes @kalai Your are correct I changed url :"getAllDansalJSON.json "  now its working .Thakyou all

Comment: ok welcome @jhone.

Answer (score 0):

I changed url:"getAllDansalJSON.html" --->  url :"getAllDansalJSON.json"

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "getAllDansalJSON.json",
    data:"", 
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout : 10000,
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
        alert(data.message);
        if (data.message=="SUCCESS") {
            alert(data);
            setMarkers(map);
        }
         else {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: "+ e);
    },
    done : function(x) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});
```